# Upstart not respawning daemon

Tags: ubuntu, upstart

I have a daemon written in C which uses the daemon() call.

I want upstart to respawn this should it fail unexpectedly.

I'm using a fairly old version of upstart, 0.3.9, on Ubuntu 8.04.

I created the following file (/etc/event.d/my-daemon):

```
start on startup
stop on shutdown
respawn
daemon
exec /usr/bin/my-daemon
```

Status:

```
# status my-daemon
my-daemon (stop) waiting
```

Start:

```
# start my-daemon

my-daemon (start) waiting
my-daemon (start) starting
my-daemon (start) pre-start
my-daemon (start) spawned, process 32631
my-daemon (start) post-start
my-daemon (start) running
```

It shows when I do `ps aux | grep my-daemon` as expected.  I then kill it using `kill -9` expecting it to respawn but issuing `ps aux` again shows nothing afterwards.  Doing `status my-daemon` I get:

```
my-daemon (start) running
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think 0.3.9 handles daemon processes as expected (something to do with it waiting around for SIGCHLDs).  A workaround for me was to just not background/daemonise the process and the respawn works.